# Python3 webscraping code

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a question:

I have a code witch opens a url and prints out the links that in the source code :

But how can I manage to save automotically all links and if there is a keyword then this link should be saved in a variable: exMPLE.

```
link = "https://www.spiegel.de"
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
for url in soup.find_all('a'):
print(url.get('href'))
```

Comment: Use a dictionary or list.  Can you provide an [Minimal Complete Verifiable 
Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: link = "https://www.spiegel.de"

Comment: sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
print(soup)
for url in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(url.get('href'))

Comment: @Dkellygb I use Beautifulsoup4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the `href` inside a (long) list using `href=True` to find all link attributes:

```
link = "https://www.spiegel.de"
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml') 
a = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

If you want to print each individual link of the list, then you would use a `for` loop.

Comment: @Ronprogramming  Fantastic no problem. Don't forget to accept if it solved your problem others may use this in the future. : )

Comment: @Ronprogramming Just press the green tick next to my answer. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer you also might like to read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Otherwise if you need some further help on this question just comment.